# Can't Set textfield to Digits & commas/dots only

Tags: java, swing, numbers, jtextfield

I'm trying to set up a program to help myself at work but I still can't cause, I can't add digit numbers to be allowed in this code:

```
char inte=evt.getKeyChar();
    if (!(Character.isDigit(inte)|| inte==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || inte==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE){
    getToolkit().beep();
        evt.consume();
```

So, im trying to get to a point to be able to add commas because i need to use floats.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? It is not very clear what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what you're trying achieve here, can you explain your thought process a little more?

Comment: see oracle tutorial - JFormatterTextField, or here is ton of code with DocumentFIlter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code should help you:

```
char c = evt.getKeyChar();
if (!(Character.isDigit(c) || c == KeyEvent.VK_COMMA || c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE || c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)) {
    getToolkit().beep();
    evt.consume();
}
```

Comment: what did you mean @sofix

Comment: Thanks for helping you just made me slap myself cause i i did not realise what i wrote over there. inste of VK_COMMA i used VK_PERIOD .